# Зачем нужны директивы условной компиляции? Их практическое применение -?

Tags: c++

Приведите пожалуйста насколько возможно простые примеры (желательно с кодом на C++).

Comment: @VTT, дубликат-то дубликат, но вразумительного ответа там нет)

Comment: @goldstar_labs чего именно там не хватает?

Comment: @älёxölüt, примеров, подробно расписан ifdef-guard, но как-то вскользь упоминаются архитектурно и платформозависимые предопределенные макросы. вообще не упомянуты отладочные msvc/gcc макросы, скудненько в общем.

Comment: @goldstar_labs а причём тут отладочные макросы? Это какие вообще имеются в виду?

Comment: @VTT нигде не могу найти эту тему-не дубликат. Скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на неё.